# How to make an object hover on collision with another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to programming and I am going through the `Unity Learn` lessons. I have a sphere rolling down a track and I want it to hover upon contact with an empty game object. I added a box collider to the empty game object. I have an error when I try to run my code.

```
public class hover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float hoverForce = 15f;

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        other.getComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * hoverForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
}
```

I tried replacing "other" with the name of the specific object I want to make hover but I still get the same error.

Comment: The "error" you didn't mention at first glance on your code is probably due to the fact that `getComponent` doesn't exist .. only `GetComponent` .. voting to close this as **typo-based**

Answer (score 0):

To make an object hover on collision with another object in **Unity**, you can use the `OnCollisionEnter2D()` method. This method is called when a collision occurs between two objects that have a `Rigidbody2D` and a `Collider2D` attached. Inside the `OnCollisionEnter2D()` method, you can set the Rigidbody2D's velocity to zero to make the object hover. You can also use other methods such as `OnTriggerEnter2D()` or `OnCollisionStay2D()` depending on your needs.

Comment: Does this work when the project is in 3D? If it helps, the error is CS1061